# Fixing CSS for Radio Button - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, radio-button

The problem: Radio Button for shipping options successfully goes to selected state which clicked, but does not show a black dot in the selected item to show to the user that it's been selected.

[image]

This is on this WooCommerce checkout page of my site. Sorry, the only way to go there is to first select an item on the store, then proceed to checkout: https://dayhikesneardenver.com/shop/

I've inspected the using google chrome inspect page and cannot for the life of me figure out if this is an issue with: 1) My Uncode theme styles, 2) WooCommerce styles, or 3) something else.

Thanks for any insight on this.

Comment: It seems to me that there is another radio button form with the same id and is making some kind of conflict. The Radio button are custom? do you have any other code or recent change you have made to the site?

Comment: No recent changes that I can think of. I'm wondering if it's a button style in my uncode theme.

Comment: I found this code in my style.css child theme. Could it be the issue?/* #Button-skins */
.style-light .btn-default,
.style-dark .style-light.style-override .btn-default,
.style-dark .style-light .btn-default {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  background-color: #258CB0 !important;
 border-color: #258CB0 !important;
 }

Comment: Try removing other custom css style on that section. Probably a conflict on styles.

Comment: Turns out it was bad code in the theme CSS. I was able to go into the child theme and override it with the following code. 

input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]{
-webkit-appearance: checkbox !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

When removing the "webkit-appearance: none" property on the radio button form or changing it (webkit-appearance: checkbox) the button appears checked.

**The properties**

[image]

I think something else is overwritting the original style of the button.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]